# How to use ST_Union with polygon and multipolygon geometry types?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry

I am attempting to combine the geometries for multiple records using the following:

```
INSERT INTO schema.boundary (name, geom)  
SELECT 'Name' ,  ST_Union(geom) FROM schema.boundary WHERE id = 0;
```

This returns the error:

```
ERROR:  Geometry type (Polygon) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)
********** Error **********
```

So I then tried the following:

```
INSERT INTO schema.boundary (name, geom)  
SELECT 'Name' ,  ST_Union(ST_Multi(geom)) FROM schema.boundary WHERE id = 0;
```

This returns the same error. I managed to combine all of the target geometry fields except for one. Checking the geometry type using `ST_GeometryType(geom)` for the all records returns 'ST MultiPolygon'. I've also tried updating the single record using ST_Multi(geom).

Is there another PostGIS function I can use to combine incompatible geometry types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that the union-ed polygon is a single part polygon and not a multipart polygon, hence failing on the insert, not on the union.

Could you try something like:

```
INSERT INTO schema.boundary (name, geom)  
SELECT 'Name' ,  ST_Multi(ST_Union(ST_Multi(geom))) FROM schema.boundary WHERE id = 0;
```

If that doesn't work, could you post the schema and some sample data that you've used to re-create the problem?

Comment: You were correct it was failing to insert for that reason. `St_Multi(ST_Union(geom))` actually worked as well. Thanks.